# Update Destination from Source in SSIS Data Flow Task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am developing a job that runs every 15 seconds that will give a "realtime" view of some of our data.

It pulls from a source on a different server that looks at a particular application.

In the past, we truncated the destination and just inserts. However, I would like to Update the destination with the new source, so we don't see a count of 4000 dip to 0, then back to 4003.

One solution is to have a temp table, then have a second task update the destination table from that temp table.

Is this the preferred way? This feels dirty.

I notice that within the Data Flow Task OLE DB Destination, I can change data access mode to SQL Command. Any idea where I can reference the source from this command? It seems logical that the data is somewhere on our side that we can manipulate.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Do you need to update changes to the rows or simply insert new rows?

Comment: Yes; I should specify -- there will only be abound 10-15 records in that table.  I will simply be updating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only doing a few records why not use a lookup to match to what you already have then either insert or update.

[image: OleSource To Lookup]

[image: QueryToMatch]

Then on no match do a `BULK INSERT` and on a match do an `UPDATE`.

Comment: This is excellent.  One feature I noticed; when the task fails (there is no mapping for that Key), it outputs the failed records, which I drop into an OLE DB Destination.  It then inserts the failed rows (Not sure this is what you meant by the Bulk Insert, but this might actually be happening on the backend).  Anyways, this works perfectly.